# Applescript Replace sub-procedure doesn't work with '@'

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm trying to substitute an email address for a symbolic character in a block of text.

The text block:

```
Dear %%FirstName%%-
... 
This message was sent to %%EmailAddress%%.
```

The script:

```
...
set theBody to my replace(theBody, "%%FirstName%%", "First")
set theBody to my replace(theBody, "%%EmailAddress%%", "first.last@company.com")
...
```

Replace sub-procedure ([AppleScript: Essential Sub-Routines](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html)):

```
on replace(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text

end replace
```

The result:

```
Dear First-
... 
This message was sent to .
```

If I change the script to:

```
...
set theBody to my replace(theBody, "%%FirstName%%", "First")
set theBody to my replace(theBody, "%%EmailAddress%%", "first.lastATcompany.com")
```

The result:

```
Dear First-
... 
This message was sent to first.lastATcompany.com.
```

What is wrong with the `replace` sub-procedure?

** edit **

I'm collecting a distinct list email addresses from an Outlook Contact:

```
...
set theAddresses to email addresses of theContact
set addressList to {}
repeat with theAddress in the theAddresses
  if addressList does not contain (address of theAddress) then
    set addressList to addressList & (address of theAddress)
  end if
end repeat
...
```

Then using the list:

```
...
repeat with theAddress in addressList
  ...
  make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{name:displayName of theContact, address:theAddress}}
  ...
end repeat
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the first example:

```
set theBody to "Dear %%FirstName%%-
... 
This message was sent to %%EmailAddress%%."

set theBody to my replace(theBody, "%%FirstName%%", "First")
set theBody to my replace(theBody, "%%EmailAddress%%", "first.last@company.com")

on replace(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end replace
```

The result was:

```
Dear First-
... 
This message was sent to first.last@company.com.
```

So it seemed to work just fine. The `replace` handler shouldn't have any problems with strings that contain special characters, so there might be something else you're missing.

Also [restoring text item delimiters is not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598385/is-restoring-text-item-delimiters-or-adding-applescripts-necessary) as far as I know, and you don't need `AppleScript's` outside tell blocks, so the `replace` handler can be simplified to something like this:

```
on replace(input, x, y)
    set text item delimiters to x
    set ti to text items of input
    set text item delimiters to y
    ti as text
end replace
```

Comment: Lauri, How did you hide your name to only show points, badges, etc?